# Storing `CheckBoxList` items in **Session** and retieveing back to `CheckBoxList`

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am storing all the items in the `CheckBoxList` in the **Session** and retrieving the same and adding to another or same `CheckBoxList`.

Here is the code where I store the `CheckBoxList` items in the Session on button1_click :

```
Session.Add("AllItems", CheckBoxList1.Items);
```

Here is the code where I retrieving the values from Session and fill the `CheckBoxList` on button2_click:

```
if ((Session["AllItems"]) != null)
        {
            CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(Session["AllItems1"].ToString());
        }
```

But this results in one item in the `CheckBoxList` whose value is: "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection"

Can someone kindly help me on this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Despite that this is a bad practice, try retrieving them using `CheckBoxList1.Items.Add((ListItemCollection)Session["AllItems1"])`

Comment: @AndreCalil: It gives a red line across the code line and says **The best overloaded method match has invalid arguments**.

Comment: Ok, try `CheckBoxList1.DataSource = (ListItemCollection)Session["AllItems1"]; CheckBoxList1.DataBind();`

Comment: Now the `CheckBoxList` is blank

Comment: OMG, there was a typo at your code. It should be `AllItems`, not `AllItems1`.

Comment: Yes, yet this results in one item in the CheckBoxList whose value is: "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection"

Answer (score 0):

```
 Session["AllItems"]= CheckBoxList1.Items;    

    if ((Session["AllItems"]) != null)
        {
        ListItemCollection listitem =(ListItemCollection)Session["AllItems"];
        foreach(ListItem item in  listitem)
         {          
         CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
         }
        }
```

Comment: the mistake was to use AddRange not Add method with AllItems session variable

Comment: Its not working, giving the same error as **The best overloaded method match has invalid arguments**

Comment: Am i storing the items of `CheckboxList` in the session correctly?

Comment: set a breakpoint in line where you set checkboxlist in session variable and another breakpoint when you test that is null or not to check the type object of session variable (with watch you will see your list value)

Comment: you can set your session variable like this Session["AllItems"]= CheckBoxList1.Items;

Comment: FYI, My `CheckBoxList1` is active in Panel2, on button_click, I save `CheckBoxList1` in Session and make Panel2 inactive, the again on button2_click, I make Panel2 active and store values of Session back to `CheckBoxList1`.

Comment: Do you clear the CheckBoxList1.Items at some point? At that point check if the Session["AllItems"] is still populated.

Comment: Yes u were so rite. I clear the CheckBoxList1. Problem solved. It works great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
> if ((Session["AllItems"]) != null)
> {
>     foreach(ListItem item in (ListItemCollection)Session["AllItems"])
>     {
>         CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(item);
>     }                
> }
> ```

Comment: Test it by using a second check box list `CheckBoxList2.Items.Add(item);` to add the session variable. Maybe something is set to clear the CheckBoxList1.Items.